# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log 1)^p+(\log 2)^p+\cdots +(\log n)^p}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the series

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log 1)^p+(\log 2)^p+\cdots +(\log n)^p}$$

where $p>0$.  For what $p$, the series converges?

This question appears in the Tier 1 Analysis exam (2014/08) of Indiana University Bloomington. And I modify it a little to make it look more tight...

Comment: Even then, your question should not be just a problem statement.  See [what the community recommends if you have no clue](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/homework-reasonable-to-have-no-clue).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a start,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log 1)^p+(\log 2)^p+\cdots +(\log n)^p}
\ge \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(\log n)^p},
$$
which diverges if $p\le 1$ (well-known and not hard to show with the standard techniques).

Further,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log 1)^p+(\log 2)^p+\cdots +(\log n)^p}
\le \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n/2 \cdot (\log (n/2))^p},
$$
which converges if $p> 1.$

Comment: The second inequality is not obvious to me when $n$ is odd. Maybe split the series into two parts, one for even $n$ and one for odd $n$?